# Run script (.bat) from ASP.Net with elevated privileges

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, service, elevated-privileges

I have a ASP.Net application from which I want to run several (BAT) scripts that require elevated privileges, because it must start and stop services, copy files, etc ...

I've tried to apply different approaches, but I can't find one that works.

This is the code from ASP.Net c#:

```
var securePass= new SecureString();
string password = "AdminPassword";
for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
{
  pass.AppendChar(password[x]);
}

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(appPath, "Scripts", "ServiceTest.bat");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UserName = adminUserName;
p.StartInfo.Domain = adminDomain;
p.StartInfo.Password = securePass;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

This is the ServiceTest.bat:

```
NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

It not works: If I remove "p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow" and "p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput" lines, the console window shows "Access denied" error executing "NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS".

I tried with Filename "**cmd.exe**", and **"/c "+Path.Combine(appPath, "Scripts", "ServiceTest.bat")** as arguments, and several ways but it not work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What privileges does your Asp.net App have? Usually it's not enough...

Comment: The user I use don't have enough rights to start SQL Service. With PsExec from @unniks response, I can change the user, but any user can start SQL Service.

Comment: Go to the Application Pools and open the Advanced Settings from the Pool of your App. Change "Identity" to a User with higher Privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different credentials. For that use RunAs or PSExec

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

https://techtorials.me/windows/using-runas-with-a-password/

E.g.
PsExec64.exe \\<local machine Name> -u Domain\Administrator -p <Password> "<Script Name>"
```

Comment: With PsExe I can execute scripts with another user. It works, but I need to start SQL Server service, and I have the same "access denied" error.

Comment: PsExec \\<Local Machine> -u Administrator -p <Password> "C:\Windows\System32\Net.exe" START MSSQLSERVER

Comment: The command **psexec \\myComputer -u myDomain\administrador -p adminPass "C:\windows\system32\net.exe" START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS** ends with **C:\windows\system32\net.exe exited with error code 2.**. I use domain administrator account.

Comment: Check the following, 1. If the path of net.exe is correct, 2. If the Domain Admin has the right to start the process. For checking access open an admin command prompt and type c:\windows\system32\net.exe start <Service Name>

Comment: I can only start the service if I open CMD.EXE with Admin privileges.